# Gravitational waves affected by dark energy

Tags: gravitational-waves, dark-energy

If the attenuation of gravitational waves with distance (from a detectable event like those LIGO has seen), could be measured, would that inform us about dark energy?

Answer (score 0):

Gravity waves' attenuation is not measurable so the question is moot. OR is it? Maybe someday we can measure such possible attenuation, even as we can for light waves.

Comment: Note that gravity waves and gravitational waves are different.